# Cart physics movement Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

I want to make a cart following rails so i made a cyclindric path and an invisible sphere that move along so i can follow the position of the sphere and apply to my cart .
There is no problem with position tracking however the rotation lookat have some issues every thing work fine when i climb forward
but if is a backward decent there is a flip on the object rotation then the camera which follow the cart rotation
I only want a solution that keep my cart looking straigth to the rail and the invisible sphere to look that he snap on rail and follow there angle.

Here is a Unitypackage of my project so that you can understand more  what is the probem :

https://mega.nz/#!IY8WCagb!UUZYmWVHCVcoSZ11_gn-L5IMnJFVVtvkrO0mZxikw9o

Thanks in adance  for your answer and your help

Answer (score 0):

Try having two spheres, one for each pair of wheels. The one sphere will obviously travel the rails a short distance in front of the second sphere. Position of your cart is in the center of the two spheres, direction of view is from rear to front sphere.

```
pos = Vector3.Lerp(front_sphere_pos, rear_sphere_pos, .5f);
orientation = Quaternion.LookRotation(front_sphere_pos - rear_sphere_pos);
```

Depending on the size of the rails and the carts it may be that the spheres touch. In that case you have to disable collision between the spheres and only have them collide with the rails.